# Handle database exceptions with php

Tags: php, mysql

This exception(error) is displayed when i try to delete a user.

```
Error: the XML response that was returned from the server is invalid.
Received:
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails                         
(`db_almacen`.`perfil_solicitud_material`, CONSTRAINT `perfil_solicitud_material_ibfk_1`
FOREIGN  KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuario` (`id_usuario`))
```

It is displayed on that way because i have a FOREIGN KEY related to my user's id.
I would like to display a different message instead of that. How can i do this i checked php exceptions manual but i didn't find an example please help me.
I am using Mysql and PHP
My php code

```
$query = "DELETE FROM unidad_solicitante where id_unid_sol ='$cod';";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Thank You

Comment: Please include the PHP code that invokes this error.

Comment: You could use try catch

Comment: Just a note that mysql_query is deprecated now and it's recommended you use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: You either need to set the [`ON DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) action for your foreign key constraint, or you need to clean up the child records of the FK relationship before deleting the parent key.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use mysql_ functions**: https://www.php.net/mysql_query

See the red box? They are deprecated, not safe, and in general it is a bad idea to use them.

If you want PHP code to throw actual `Exception`, then use [PDO](https://www.php.net/PDO); If you want to produce safe code, then use [PDO](https://www.php.net/PDO); If you don't want dark demons (also applies to script kiddies) of SQL injection to get your site down, use... you know what :) mysql_ functions are wrong, mysql_ functions are evil, mysql_ functions are waking up dark forces , mysql_ functions will steal the ice cream from your child, mysql_ functions are voting in senate, mysql_ functions aren't feeding their dog; mysql_ functions will haunt you at night; mysql_ functions are selling drugs on the streets;

This fragment of your query code: `='$cod';` seems vulnerable, so please read this:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

With PDO, you can handle any exception with the usual `try{} catch(...){}` block;

If you cannot use PDO or really really do not want to, you should check if `mysql_query()` returned `true`, if not, then your error message will be returned by `mysql_error()`, so it will be something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
if(!$result) {
    $error = mysql_error();
    // .. handle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any mysql error is going to trigger the `or die(...)`, because mysql_query() will return a plain boolean FALSE to signal the failure. If you want to exempt certain error conditions from the die(), you'll have to test for them explicitly:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    switch(mysql_errno()) {
      case 1216: ... foreign key error ...
      case xxx: ...
      default:
            die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

The error codes are defined here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html

Answer (score 0):

The code responsible for displaying database error is here:

```
die(mysql_error())
```

- die() function terminates the script and displays a message
- mysql_error() outputs last error connected with executing MySQL query

If you want to display your own message use the following code:

```
if(mysql_query($query)) {
    echo 'success';
}
else {
    echo 'error';
}
```